# Como saber quantas vendas para cada um dos meses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Preciso montar uma consulta que traga o total de vendas de cada mês a partir de uma tabela chamada `sales.SalesOrderHeader`, mas não estou conseguindo. Nesta tabela há um campo `OrderDate` que é a data da venda e `TotalDue` é o valor da venda. Essa é a minha tentativa:

```
select a.Year, a.Month
from
(
select distinct cast(year(orderdate) as varchar) + '_' +
case when month(OrderDate) < 10 then '0' else '' end + cast(month(OrderDate)as varchar) as Year_Month,
sum(TotalDue) as Total
From sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by month(OrderDate), OrderDate
) a
group by a.Month 
order by 1
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está mal formulada.
Por favor mostre as estruturas das tabelas para que possamos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Qual é a estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: De bater o olho, parece que falta selecionar na query externa a coluna `Total` definida na subquery.

Comment: `order by 1` - Qual é a finalidade disso?

Answer (score 2):

A consulta interna tem um campo `Year_Month` e a externa tem `Year` e `Month` separados. Assim sendo, vou dividir o `Year_Month` em dois para ficar como a consulta externa precisa. Fazendo-se essa separação, elimina-se também a dificuldade/complexidade de ter que lidar com os meses 1-9 como sendo 01-09.

Além disso, o `Total` não é usado na consulta externa, mas é isso que você precisa lá para saber o total das vendas por mês.

Não é necessário agrupar-se duas vezes, portanto só um `GROUP BY` é necessário. A ordenação é dada cronologicamente pelo `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT a.Year, a.Month, a.Total
FROM (
    SELECT
        YEAR(s.OrderDate) AS Year,
        MONTH(s.OrderDate) AS Month,
        SUM(s.TotalDue) AS Total
    FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader s
    GROUP BY YEAR(s.OrderDate), MONTH(s.OrderDate)
) a
ORDER BY a.Year, a.Month
```